# How to get specific Div's/Card Details when user clicked that using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, card

[image]I am creating various cards using fetch API, this cards are holding details like (Author, Title, Cover Image, etc.).

There is a lot of cards renders there once API call my struggle is how to get specific card data/details like ( author, title etc.) of clicked card. when user clicked any of the card from these set.

HTML

```
        <div class="row" id="ShowReports">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mt-3" onclick="show(this)" id="card">
            <div class="card p-1">
                <img src="https://d3i5mgdwi2ze58.cloudfront.net/znuxxu2npw851eeboqayu3e35udn" alt="image"
                    class="bookimg" width="150" height="200">
                <h6 class="mb-3 booktitle">${title1}</h6>
                <p class="mb-0 bookpara" name="author">Author : ${author1}</p>
                <p class="mb-3 bookpara" name="pages">Pages : ${pages1}</p>
                <a href="${downloadLinks}" class="reportbtn">Download1</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mt-3" onclick="show(this)" id="card">
            <div class="card p-1">
                <img src="https://d3i5mgdwi2ze58.cloudfront.net/znuxxu2npw851eeboqayu3e35udn" alt="image"
                    class="bookimg" width="150" height="200">
                <h6 class="mb-3 booktitle">${title2}</h6>
                <p class="mb-0 bookpara" name="author">Author : ${author2}</p>
                <p class="mb-3 bookpara" name="pages">Pages : ${pages2}</p>
                <a href="${downloadLinks}" class="reportbtn">Download2</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

javaScript

```
function show() {
var details = this.innerHTML
console.log(details)
```

}

Don't know what is the right approach or method to this...

Comment: You're passing 1 parameter when calling "show" function but you didn't handle it when defining the function.

Comment: @SachinVairagi thanks for the comment bro actually i tried show(this) but that not working can you help me out by providing any solution or code bro ??

Comment: @Bravo can you show the example cuase i have already mention onclick in html div even if i tried funtion show(this) thats not working too..

Comment: You can try this 
<div onclick="show(event)"></div>function theFunction(e)
{ console(e.target);}

Comment: @SachinVairagi this is working somehow it's still not the whole solution i want whole detail of that card at once not target area.. what i am looking to do is that when someone is clicked on card it will popup the window containing all details of that particular like author book title etc...

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATED**

We need to assign unique id to data elements. For example: `id="${id}-author"`. Note that id is from your card id

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mt-3" onclick="show(${id})" id="card">
            <div class="card p-1">
                <img src="https://d3i5mgdwi2ze58.cloudfront.net/znuxxu2npw851eeboqayu3e35udn" alt="image"
                    class="bookimg" width="150" height="200">
                <h6 class="mb-3 booktitle" id="${id}-booktitle">${title1}</h6>
                <p class="mb-0 bookpara" name="author" id="${id}-author">Author : ${author1}</p>
                <p class="mb-3 bookpara" name="pages" id="${id}-pages">Pages : ${pages1}</p>
                <a href="${downloadLinks}" class="reportbtn">Download1</a>
            </div>
</div>
```

After that, we can implement `show` function like below

```
function show(id) {
   const author = document.getElementById(id + "-author").innerHTML;
   const booktitle = document.getElementById(id + "-booktitle").innerHTML;
   const pages = document.getElementById(id + "-pages").innerHTML;
   console.log({ author, booktitle, pages })
}
```

If you don't want to modify HTML, you also can try this way

```
onclick="show({ author: ${author}, booktitle: ${booktitle}, pages: ${pages} })"
```

And you need to have params corresponding to your data name

```
function show({ author, booktitle, pages }) {
   console.log({ author, booktitle, pages })
}
```

**OLD ANSWER**

```
onclick="show(this)"
```

`this` in this context is referred to the global one, but from my understanding of your question, you're trying to get scoped context, so the change could be

```
onclick="show(event)"
```

To access the `innerHTML` from that click, you can try this way

```
function show(event) { //the param needs to be passed properly
   var currentElement = event.target || event.srcElement;
   var details = currentElement.innerHTML
   console.log(details)
}
```

P/s: If you want to keep the global context on `this`, you also need to pass the param on `show` function.

Comment: hey, thanks for the comment, actually this code pretty much near what i want but still problem is it giving clicked target element instead I want whole card details at once so when user click on any card it will popup a ,modal box containing details about this card including description ...so is it possible to get all card details at once...i don't know what i missing

Comment: I updated my answer for the sake of your requirement, I think it works well because you already have `ShowReports` id which is the wrapper for all card details @KuldeepSingh

Comment: I appreciate your help buddy, But I think the approach is need to change here totally. actually now its getting me whole html content instead i just want single card details only which is clicked from multiple cards already there is book website so i want that single click card book details in popup modal box

Comment: Let me try to understand your problem again, so you want to have `booktitle` and `bookpara` whenever the user clicks on that target element containing all this info? @KuldeepSingh

Comment: @KuldeepSingh the target element on that `onClick` is the single card container for all single card details, right? Or you put `onClick` somewhere else?

Comment: hey buddy thanks struggle with me btw finally I figure out i found a way around which working just way I want...thanks for the help. :)

Comment: @KuldeepSingh - You can share your solution, it might be helpful for others.

Comment: Congrats, bro! @KuldeepSingh

Comment: @Nick Vu ? i put onclick="show(id) on last div just just above img tag so now details containing element became its children i also i will assign unique id while calling API when rendering the card but now other struggle is how to get children's inner html method do you know how to get child elements inner HTML ?

Comment: @SachinVairagi I will once I get to know how to target child elements and get their innerHTML. then i will post what i did...

Comment: Could you update your question to what you've done so far? Without code, it's hard to understand your situation tho @KuldeepSingh

Comment: @nick Vu okay, in short : I am creating a book download website so once fetch AI call its render multiple card on page containing book cover and its titile and details so what i want to do when user click any card then it will popup the modal box containing details and description of that book cause description page long i will put that in modal box cant add them in card i have shared image above you can check also....hope this understandable sorry for bad english

Comment: I cannot explain here shortly, so I updated my answer instead. You can check it out again @KuldeepSingh

Answer (score 1):

@ Nick Vu thanks for your comment your approach is quite logical and great well what i have did is, I have assigned a unique id to every card div while calling API and then target its childnode's innerHTMLS.

HTML

```
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mt-3" id="card">
            <div class="card p-1" id="second" onclick="show(id)">
                <img src="https://d3i5mgdwi2ze58.cloudfront.net/znuxxu2npw851eeboqayu3e35udn" alt="image"
                    class="bookimg" width="150" height="200">
                <h6 class="mb-3 booktitle">${title2}</h6>
                <p class="mb-0 bookpara" name="author">Author : ${author2}</p>
                <p class="mb-3 bookpara" name="pages">Pages : ${pages2}</p>
                <a href="${downloadLinks}" class="reportbtn">Download2</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

javascript

```
function show(e) {
console.log(e)
var details = document.getElementById(e)
console.log(details)
console.log(details.childNodes[1].src)
console.log(details.childNodes[3].innerHTML)
console.log(details.childNodes[5].innerHTML)
console.log(details.childNodes[7].innerHTML)
```

}

this is working around what i want as output.. thanks. Or may be at last i can do forEach loop of childnodes to make it more short.

Comment: That's good tho! but I have a small comment here that if you change the HTML structure, your `show` function with element indices will be broken, so I'd suggest you should go along with element ids instead element indices